# SimpleLevelLoader class not found in AndEngine GLES2

Tags: andengine

Am new in AndEngine. While working from [a AndEngine Tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-11.html) , following classes are not found. I tried with importing all libraries from AndEngine but class are still not found.

Classes are :

```
SimpleLevelLoader
EntityLoader
SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData
```

Please help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending few hours finally I got the issue.

Actually I was using `GLES2` which has no such classes .

For those classes we need `GLES2-AnchorCenter`, which is latest update from AndEngine. I only replaced `GLES2 AndEngine with GLES2-AnchorCenter AndEngine` and now Its working fine.

In `AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension` I replaced class named `AreaShape` with `IShape`in few classes.

Comment: Thats why you should read all articles carefully next time, in first article I highlighted what andengine branch you need, unfortunately a lot of viewers just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody is getting confused because the GITHUB download page for AndEngine has "GLES2" and not the "GLES2-AnchorCenter" as the default +  at the AndEngine tutorial page the videos have embededed links that point to the default download page and don't highlight the fact that you have to choose the right branch from the branches dropdown menu. Most developers not familiarized with GITHUB (yes, there are a lot) won't even notice that.

It would be less error prone if we just point the user to the right branches 
e.g. https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter instead of the base one.